# QGIS .tiff to shapefiles by extracting colours

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, color-ramp, vectorization

So I have the following raster file:
[image]

I would like to edit it so that I export all green, blue or purple areas as a single, new .tiff. Afterwards I would make a vectorization to be able to process the data for my purposes.

How would you proceed?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: classify?  https://www.igismap.com/image-classification-in-qgis-supervised-and-unsupervised-classification/

Answer (score 0):

Got a working solution:

1. "Raster" -> "Conversion" -> "Polygonize" -> choose "Band number" : "Band1" for red
2. Check which Band1 value you are looking for by "identifying features" in raster (in my case the green part had the value 153)
3. "Filter" the feature of the shape by the Band1 values you want to extract